# Will this SQL snippet REINDEX my GIN index? Why is it renaming an old index onto another?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.3, index-tuning, disk-space

I have a large PostgreSQL 9.3 database. One index on one table is quite large and appears to be bloated. I am using [pgcompact from pgtoolkit](https://github.com/grayhemp/pgtoolkit) to reduce database bloat without heavy table locks. However it would not reindex that large index, since it's a GIN index. It suggested this SQL snippet as a way to reindex this index. (`mytable` is the table, `myindex` is the index. `myindex` is just a GIN index on the `nodes` (bigint) column of `mytable`).

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY pgcompact_index_17791 ON mytable USING gin (nodes) WITH (fastupdate=off);
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL statement_timeout TO 1000;
ALTER INDEX public.myindex RENAME TO pgcompact_temp_index_17791;
ALTER INDEX public.pgcompact_index_17791 RENAME TO myindex;
END;
DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY public.pgcompact_temp_index_17791;
```

Will this snippet actually reindex the `myindex` index and reduce <strike>table</strike> *index* bloat?

What is the point of renaming the old index (`myindex`) to the name of the temporary index (`pgcompact_temp_index_17791`), and then renaming it back again? Won't that result in overwriting the currently being created temp index and then just renaming it back, meaning that `myindex` isn't rebuilt at all? The author of pgtoolkit appears quite knowledgeable, but I don't understand how this works, and I don't want to run SQL on my database without understanding it.

If this approach works, what's the difference between this and doing `REINDEX INDEX myindex;`?

Comment: Re-creating an index will only reduce *index* bloat, never *table* bloat. The renaming is not really necessary unless you rely on that index name somewhere in your application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, you're right., I mistyped. *Index bloat* is all I'm concerned with here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the names more carefully.  `pgcompact_temp_index_17791` and `pgcompact_index_17791` are not the same thing.

The reason to rename the old index is that you can't do "drop index concurrently" inside of a transaction.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you for spotting that! I clearly didn't read that closely enough.